# Creating File Associations in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, file-association

How would one go about associating a file type with his application? I know how to read the command line arguments but I am not sure how I can "register" the file extension with Windows. Furthermore, my application is a stand-alone executable, so how would I keep Windows up-to-date on the location of my program?

I did a fair amount of searching and all I could find were old articles that didn't explain everything. How can I create file associations to a stand-alone executable in VB.NET?

Comment: How are you deploying the application? ClickOnce? Installer Package? Copy and run?

Comment: Simply building and distributing the executable.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is handled by the registry. If you want to make your program self-register it's current location when run see this example.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/System_File_Association.aspx